# Conditionally adding several filters to a SQLAlchemy query without duplicating code

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model:

```
class Ticket(db.Model):

 __tablename__ = 'ticket'

 id = db.Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False,
 autoincrement=True)
 cluster = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(128))

 @classmethod
 def get(cls, cluster=None):
     query = db.session.query(Ticket)

     if cluster is not None:
         query = query.filter(Ticket.cluster==cluster)

     return query.one()
```

If I add a new column and would like to extend the `get` method, I have to add one `if xxx is not None` like this below:

```
 @classmethod
 def get(cls, cluster=None, user=None):
     query = db.session.query(Ticket)

     if cluster is not None:
         query = query.filter(Ticket.cluster==cluster)
     if user is not None:
         query = query.filter(Ticket.user==user)

     return query.one()
```

Is there any way I could make this more efficient? If I have too many columns, the `get` method would become so ugly.

Comment: Is this targeting Python 2 or 3?

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't call your old code _inefficient_. Unrolling loops is something compilers typically do as an optimization, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, if you don't want to write something repetitive, use a loop:

```
@classmethod
def get(cls, **kwargs):
    query = db.session.query(Ticket)
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        query = query.filter(getattr(table, k) == v)
    return query.one()
```

Because we're no longer setting the `cluster=None`/`user=None` as defaults (but instead depending on things that weren't specified by the caller simply never being added to `kwargs`), we no longer need to prevent filters for null values from being added: The only way a null value will end up in the argument list is if the user *actually asked to search* for a value of `None`; so this new code is able to honor that request should it ever take place.

If you prefer to retain the calling convention where `cluster` and `user` can be passed positionally (but the user can't search for a value of `None`), see [the initial version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63979938/1).